# It takes X time

Tags: phrase-requests

Kiam oni volas esprimi la necesan tempon por fari ion, kiu estas la plej ofta verbo? Necesi (mi uzas tiun) daŭri aŭ alia? 
Mi vidis ekzemple: necesas multe da tempo por fari tion. Daŭras unu horon piediri tien. Ĉu oni uzus "uzi" en aliaj frazoj ekzemple mi uzis kvin tagojn fari ĝin. I took 5 days to do it. Ne ŝajnas ke tiu frazero aperas ofte en lernolibroj, libroj ĝenerale, sed ĝi estas utila kaj ofta frazero.

Answer (score 4):

To the various suggestions, I would add:

- *Necesis kvin tagoj por fari ĝin.*

Answer (score 3):

> I took 5 days to do it.

Eble: Mi bezonis kvin tagojn por fari ĝin.

Mi trovis similajn ekzemplojn en la Tekstaro:

- meze inteligenta leganto bezonas kvin sekundojn por orientiĝi
- ŝi bezonis du fojojn eniri la ĉambron, por ke oni povu ŝin rimarki
- Li bezonos duonan tagon por fari la vojon
- Jen vi bezonos du semajnojn, ĝis kiam vi regos la trukon.

Comment: Plian demandeton: ĉu la malsamo inter ĝis kaj ĝis kiam estas la sama kiel inter post/post kiam kaj antaŭ/antaŭ ol?

Comment: Oni uzas "post kiam" kaj "antaŭ ol" por enkonduki subfrazon. Oni ofte uzas "ĝis kiam" en la sama maniero. Tamen, laŭ PMEG, en nedemanda subfrazo, "aldomi kiam estas superflue, eĉ evitinde": http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/aliaj.html#i-3s4

Answer (score 3):

Kiam nur estas formala subjekto (*it* en la angla), mi pensas ke *daŭras* (kiun vi menciis) estas la plej bona verbo.

- Reading the book took five days.

  - Legi la libron daŭris kvin tagojn.

Se estas alia subjekto mi rekomendas *bezoni* same kiel Sambuko.

- It took me five days to read the book.

  - Mi bezonis kvin tagojn por legi la libron.

Answer (score 2):

> Ĉu oni uzus "uzi" en aliaj frazoj ekzemple mi uzis kvin tagojn fari
>   ĝin. I took 5 days to do it.

Mi faris ĝin dum kvin tagoj

Ĝin mi faris dum kvin tagoj

Mi ĝin faris dum kvin tagoj

Comment: "I took five days to do it" sugestas ke "mi" finis la taskon. "Mi faris gxin dum kvin tagoj" sugestas ke la tasko ne havas finon. (I did it for five days.)

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Mi finis gxin dum kvin tagoj.

Comment: I finished it over five days.